# Is it possible to schedule multiple selectors or update callbacks on single CCNode object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d 2.0

in my layer class I am scheduling a method

```
[self schedule:@selector(myMethod:) ];
```

then in the same layer I scheduling another method like this

```
[[self scheduler]scheduleSelector:@selector(mySecondMethod) forTarget:self interval:enemySpawnSpeed paused:NO];
```

When I run the code it says 'CCScheduler. Trying to schedule a selector with a pause value different than the target'

when I comment any one of these lines my project runs ok and give no errors. Is it impossible to schedule multiple selectors with a same node ? or am I doing something wrong here ?

after reading the guide http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:draw_update I am not sure but I think we can only schedule one selector per node

Comment: why are you using [self scheduler]?

Comment: Yes, you can schedule multiple selectors. Do you return *[CCDirector Scheduler]* in the scheduler getter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this works:

```
[self scheduleSelector:@selector(myMethod:)];
[self scheduleSelector:@selector(mySecondMethod:)];
```

Your `mySecondMethod` selector was missing a colon at the end. The error you got was related to the paused flag, you should have used `self.paused` instead of using NO to ensure the selector's paused state is the same as the target's.

Also that second line is odd, did you try to schedule updates from outside the class? If so, simply send a message to the layer object (ie `scheduleMySecondMethod`) that then schedules the selector.

Comment: if I am coding inside the init method of a layer shouldn't I send messages to its scheduler property ? that is what I am doing in the second line. and thanks for telling about self.paused instead of NO it helped.

Comment: Each node class has [self schedule*..] methods, see: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/KoboldTouch/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_node.html#afe99d609f17c4c849e4543805ffeceab You used it correctly in the first example, there's no reason to use the scheduler nor is 'scheduler' a standard property of nodes.